# Overloading "link-to" helper in ember.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js

I'm trying to make a custom helper that does the same thing that link-to, except with a few more assumptions.

I'm trying to make this:

`{{#my-link-to widget.href}}{{widget.title}}{{/my-link-to}}`

It takes the route parameters only (widget.href), and the route is assumed to be 'root'. Here's how I'm implementing it:

```js
Ember.Handlebars.registerHelper('my-link-to', function() {
  var args = [].slice.call(arguments);
  args.unshift('root'); // always use the 'root' route

  return Ember.Handlebars.helpers['link-to'].apply(this, args);
});
```

However, my resulting links turn out to be all pointing to `/#` and I get a `This link-to is in an inactive loading state because at least one of its parameters presently has a null/undefined value, or the provided route name is invalid.` error.

Doing `{{#my-link-to 'root' widget.href}}{{widget.title}}{{/my-link-to}}` and removing `args.unshift('root')` works as expected.

I have a fiddle demonstrating this here: http://jsfiddle.net/p2R9y/3/

I'm really new to Ember.js so let me know if I'm doing something blatantly wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each argument passed to a handlebars view helper have some additional informantion. So `args.unshift('root');` isn't enough you need to say what "root" means: a binding a string literal etc. In your case is a string literal, because the expected usage is:

```
{{#my-link-to-works 'root' widget.href}}
```

You need to use `STRING` in the options hash `types` key

```
Ember.Handlebars.registerHelper('my-link-to-fails', function() {
  var args = [].slice.call(arguments),
      options = args[args.length-1]; // last argument is always the options hash

  args.unshift('root');
  // the types says what is the type of each argument, in that case we need STRING
  options.types.unshift('STRING');

  return Ember.Handlebars.helpers['link-to'].apply(this, args);
});
```

I updated your fiddle with this code please give a look http://jsfiddle.net/marciojunior/sR96j/

Comment: Thank you! I suspected it was something that was passed through in the 'this' or 'arguments' context when the handler is run.

Answer (score 0):

I think figured your problem.

**1. You got your example mixed up**

You are adding `'root'` to the `my-link-to-works` helper:

```
{{#my-link-to-works 'root' widget.href}}
```

and doing the unshift on the `my-link-to-fails` helper. So actually both examples are different. One has two arguments (ex: 'root' and '/widget/foo') and the other only has one (ex: '/widget/foo').

**2. Anyway, why does it work when the first argument is 'root'?**

The [link-to helper](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Handlebars.helpers.html#method_link-to) first argument must be a `routeName`. This helper can also receive a second argument [supplying an explicit dynamic segment value](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Handlebars.helpers.html#toc_supplying-an-explicit-dynamic-segment-value) which appends it's value to the resolved route. This was how your arguments were interpreted. If you check your example, the working links resolve to, for example, `#//widget/foo`. You may notice the two forward slashes there, which are a result of your resolved route `#/` + your segment value `/widget/foo`.

**3. Solution?**

Use the link-to helper directly: `{{link-to 'widget' 'widget.href'}}` and remove the `/widget/` part from your href strings or do something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/tqFJ3/4/

The helper: (this is the same as using `link-to` directly)

```
Ember.Handlebars.registerHelper('my-link-to-works', function() {
  // Do extra stuff here...
  return Ember.Handlebars.helpers['link-to'].apply(this, arguments);
});
```

Change your widgets href and leave only the dynamic segments:

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model : function() {
        return {
            widgets: [
              { href: 'foo' },
              { href: 'bar' },
              { href: 'baz' }
            ]
        };
    }
});
```